# Run QGIS Model on selected features only?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-modeler

Would it be possible to run a script in a QGIS model so that it only runs on selected features from an input layer? I don't want to use the option in the toolbox options as I have other models that require to run without selections.

I just a model to only run on selected features in the input layer and return an error if no feature is selected. I'm thinking a script added immediately after the input in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer by [@underdark ♦](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/187/underdark) is correct in that you could use the **Save selected features** algorithm. However, as you mentioned, if no features are selected then it saves all features.

Building on from your [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243248/ensure-model-runs-from-a-specific-layer), we could add another `if` statement to the script to check if any features are selected. If yes then run the mentioned algorithm, otherwise show an error:

```
##Example=name
##input_layer=vector
##output=output vector

from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.gui import QgsMessageBar

layer = processing.getObject(input_layer)
# Add your names into the list within single quotes
allowed_layers = ['map', 'layerName2', 'layerName3']

if layer.name() in allowed_layers:
    if layer.selectedFeatures():        
        processing.runalg('qgis:saveselectedfeatures', layer, output)
    else:
        iface.messageBar().pushWidget(iface.messageBar().createMessage( u'No features selected' ), QgsMessageBar.WARNING, 3)
else:
    iface.messageBar().pushWidget(iface.messageBar().createMessage( u'Layer not allowed' ), QgsMessageBar.WARNING, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you but I need this to be separate from the other model. I've tried taking out parts of the script relating to the name but it won't run. I don't really know Python. I really want a model to run on any layer but only if a feature is selected and to return an error if no feature is selected. ;)

Comment: Got it. I was getting an indent error but I've managed to sort it. Thanks for your help. ;)

Comment: @webg - Most welcome, glad you got it to work :)

Comment: After upgrading to 2.18.13 this script no longer seems to work. I get this.. Parameters: INPUT_LAYER "=C:\Users\Will\AppData\Local\Temp\processing8c9f09fbe2fd45f19ac2bbc41972cdc8\53509f25301645bcb6190158cdfe229c\output.shp
Failed

Error executing algorithm Save selected features There are no selected features in the input layer."
If I remove the script the model works.

Comment: @webg - Which QGIS version did you use beforehand? I would suggest asking a [new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and include a screenshot of your model and the script you use (I just tested a simple model with this script on 2.18.13 and it works fine).

Comment: I was using 2.14. I've asked a new question with images. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258486/model-script-works-in-qgis-2-14-but-not-2-18

Answer (score 7):

Adding **Save selected features** should do the trick:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but adding Save Selected Features doesn't prevent my model from running if there are no selected features in the input layer which I need it to do.