# Model script works in QGIS 2.14 but not 2.18

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-modeler, qgis-2.18

I created a model that worked fine in QGIS 2.14. With help I included a script in the model that prevented the model from running unless a feature was selected. But after upgrading to 2.18 the model no longer runs unless I remove the script.

Model

[image]

Error

[image]

Script

[image]

The above does exactly what I want it to do in 2.14 so I don't understand why it won't in 2.18. I have a couple of other models that use the same script for the same purpose and have the same issue. I have tried this on my PC at home and on my work PCs and still have the same issue.

Comment: your script looks good, but I don't understand why you use the selectedfeature algorithm again (from the output of your script). No features are selected in this output and that's why you get the error.

Comment: Ah! I removed the selected feature algorithm and it works. Weird why it worked fine as it was in 2.14 but not in 2.18 though. I included that algorithm when I created the model on someone else's advice. Thanks for the helpful response.

Comment: Can you reopen the question to post the answer  I gave.  DDon't understand why it's closed

Comment: Please always provide code and error messages as text rather than pictures.