# Run graphical modeler on multiple pairs of selected features

Tags: qgis, merge, qgis-modeler, workflow

I have a shapefile of 10,000+ county polygons. Of these, I've identified ~5,000 that are geographically too small, and I want to combine with their immediate nearest neighbor, naming the combined county A and county B "A - B"

Current workflow:

1. Manually select the two counties I want to combine
2. Click "Merge Selected Features"
3. Manually specify output fields and concatenations
4. Click "OK"

I want to be able to manually select the two counties (some human judgment is required for that part), then run the model so it runs steps 2-4 *only* on those two selected features.

I've been digging around for a while and can't seem to find an answer for this. [This was close](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243525/run-qgis-model-on-selected-features-only), but I will have thousands of these pairs, and I don't want to select two, save them as a new file, then run the model that merges them.

That asker's [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243248/ensure-model-runs-from-a-specific-layer) was also close, but I'm wondering if it's possible to do this 100% in the graphical modeler.